# SET ARITHABORT ON doesn't avoid error on Insert

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns, arithabort

We have a stored procedure that inserts into a staging table with a computed column. The proc is called from bcp and is throwing an error because `ARITHABORT` is disabled at the Database level. I added SET `ARITHABORT` ON at the beginning of the proc, right after the `BEGIN` clause, but still getting the error. How can we get rid of this error without setting the database level? If this is not possible, what kind of issues can we have if enable the setting at the database level?

Answer (score 0):

Add following code at beginning of your Proc and try it.

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
```